# Best Practices for modularizing Selenium RC test scripts

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, selenium-rc

I am creating Selenium RC test scripts in Visual Studio (C#). I am
struggling with re-factoring the tests; all my tests are in a single
file. I would appreciate any input and/or pointers to websites, books,
etc. to learn about modularizing the tests.

I have to run the same tests on different sites (same application but
configured differently for different clients and logins) which are 95%
same. Would anybody like to provide some good examples or best
practices to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Best practise for writing Selenium tests or any UI tests is [Page Object Model](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/page-object-pattern.htm) which is the idea that you create an Object for each of the pages. Each of these objects abstract the page so when you write a test it doesnt really look like you have been working with Selenium.

So for a blog you would do something like this to create an object for the home page

```
public class Home
{
    private readonly ISelenium _selenium;

    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiates a new Home Page object. Pass in the Selenium object created in the test SetUp(). 
    /// When the object in instantiated it will navigate to the root
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selenium">Selenium Object created in the tests
    public Home(ISelenium selenium)
    {
        this._selenium = selenium;
        if (!selenium.GetTitle().Contains("home"))
        {
            selenium.Open("/");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Navigates to Selenium Tutorials Page. Selenium object wll be passed through
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>SeleniumTutorials representing the selenium_training.htm</returns>
    public SeleniumTutorials ClickSelenium()
    {
        _selenium.Click("link=selenium");
        _selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
        return new SeleniumTutorials(_selenium);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Click on the blog or blog year and then wait for the page to load
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="year">blog or blog year
    /// <returns>Object representing /blog.* pages</returns>
    public Blog ClickBlogYear(string year)
    {
        _selenium.Click("link=" + year);
        _selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
        return new Blog(_selenium);
    }
    // Add more methods as you need them
}
```

then you would create a test that looks like the following

```
[TestFixture]
public class SiteTests
{
    private ISelenium selenium;
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk");
        selenium.Start();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Teardown()
    {
        selenium.Stop();
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldLoadHomeThenGoToXpathTutorial()
    {
        Home home = new Home(selenium);
        SeleniumTutorials seleniumTutorials = home.ClickSelenium();
        SeleniumXPathTutorial seleniumXPathTutorial = seleniumTutorials.ClickXpathTutorial();
        Assert.True(seleniumXPathTutorial.
                    IsInputOnScreen(SeleniumXPathTutorial.FirstInput));
        Assert.True(seleniumXPathTutorial
                    .IsInputOnScreen(SeleniumXPathTutorial.SecondInput));
        Assert.True(seleniumXPathTutorial
                    .IsInputOnScreen(SeleniumXPathTutorial.Total));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea. One more more question: should every test be for verifying one specific UI action?

Comment: each test should test one workflow but remember to never allow tests to rely on each other

Comment: This results in selenium being started and stopped for each test run. Is this ideal? It can be quite a slow process. What about instantiating the selenium object outside of Setup and just returning to the Home page in the Setup method to return to a base page? You may retain some state between tests in the browser, but this might be ok for a set of related tests